# Errors with ISE iMPACT obtaining JTAG chain

Tags: fpga, xilinx, jtag

I am trying to program the ARM processor of a TE 0720-01, which is attached to the carrier board TE 0701-03. I have been following the instructions listed on this [site](https://wiki.trenz-electronic.de/display/4X5B/TE0701+JTAG+Programming+Guide), in the section "Xilinx Zynq (TE0720 Zynq SoC module) Programming".

The issue I am having is initializing the JTAG chain, where once I try to do so, iMPACT gives me the error:

*ERROR:iMPACT - A problem may exist in the hardware configuration. Check that the cable, scan chain, and power connections are intact, that the specified scan chain configuration matches the actual hardware, and that the power supply is adequate and delivering the correct voltage.*

I am using a Male-A to Mini-B USB cable, to connect the board to the computer. I have searched online for the longest time now but cannot find any answers.

Comment: Did oyu re-program the CPLD on the board in accordance to the information on the page? Because with a CPLD in the chain, it is pretty hard to figure out where the problem is located. Do a search for "Digilent JTAG" and see if you can get any help there.

Comment: If you send some more info, it will be easier to help you. If you send the image capture of the JTAG chain as it is seen by the IMPACT. If oyu can not access the JTAG at all, then you should check the voltage on your JTAG connector, make sure your ground is connected properly and verify that the JTAG chain is actually connected to the wright signals.